# How do I get the value of a cell in a loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of a cell related to the row to calculate the difference of the values in another cell that I want to add of the same row.

the snippet shows what I mean by wanting to get the data from the same row on any row that i land on and only that selected row in that instance. Other than that it has nothing to do with the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(7).css('background-color', 'green');
  $('tbody tr').eq(3).find('td').eq(7).css('background-color', 'green');
  $('tbody tr').eq(4).find('td').eq(7).css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

this is my jquery code to get the value from the cells

```
$(document).on('blur', '.price', function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id1");
        var price = $(this).text();
        edit_data(id, price, "price");
    });
```

I tried to fix this is by adding:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.price', function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id1");
        var price = $(this).text();
        edit_data(id, price, "price");

        var id2 = $('.final_price').data("id2");
        var final_price = $('.final_price').text();

        var diff_total = final_price - price;
        edit_data(id, diff_total, "diff");

    });
```

the jquery code above returns a string of all final_price values in every cell that I have

this is the code for the table but as you can see it is an array the return multiple cells and each cell has its own value

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db");  
$output = '';  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sample ORDER BY id DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$output .= '
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
    <th width="10%">Id</th>
    <th width="40%">Price</th>
    <th width="40%">Final Price</th>
    <th width="10%">Delete</th>
    </tr>';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $final_price_total = 0;
    $price_total = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
            <td class="price" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["price"].'</td>
            <td class="final_price" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["final_price"].'</td>
            <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>
            </tr>
            ';
            $final_price_total += $row["final_price"];
            $price_total += $row["price"];
        }
        $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="price_total" id="price_total" name="price_total" value="'.$price_total.'" contenteditable>'.$price_total.'</td>
            <td class="final_price_total" id="final_price_total" name="final_price_total" value="'.$final_price_total.'" contenteditable>'.$final_price_total.'</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            ';
        $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="price" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="final_price" contenteditable></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>
            </tr>
            ';
}
else{
    $output .= '<tr>
    <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>
    </tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>
</div>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to read the final price of the same row i.e. inside parent tr of price. following code will work.

```
$(document).on('blur', '.price', function(){
        var $el = $(this);
        var id = $el.data("id1");
        var price = $el.text();
        edit_data(id, price, "price");

        var $fel = $el.parents('tr:first').find('.final_price');
        var id2 = $fel.data("id2");
        var final_price = $fel.text();

        var diff_total = final_price - price;
        edit_data(id, diff_total, "diff");

    });
```

Comment: "parents" function returns all parents but we need only immediate tr parent inside which our final price is. so with "tr:first" it returns the first tr parent and ignore others. :)

Comment: Then why not just parent?

Comment: I wasn't sure if "price" is a td.

Comment: also it would make the code future proof for any html structure/hierarchy changes.